# Trying to Load google places autocomplete 2 times on one page

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-places-api

I am trying to load google autocomplete on two places in my page. One in the nav bar for searching the site and the second for the user to create an event by entering the address. I can get either one or the other working. And once I got both working but then it wouldn't fill in the info. I'd love to know what I am doing wrong, I have been banging my head against this for a hours now.

My inputs are

```
<input class="form-control" id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="term">
and
 <input id="autocomplete2" placeholder="Enter address to store" type="text" autocomplete="off"></input>
```

and my js file

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;

var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', addlatlong);

  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById('autocomplete2'), {
     types: [ 'geocode' ] 
   });
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}
function addlatlong() {

var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
  var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();


  document.getElementById("latbox").value = latitude;
  document.getElementById("lngbox").value = longitude;

  console.log(`${latitude}`)
  console.log(`${longitude}`)

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, let's make sure those inputs are identical other than their ID's.

Here's a .slim example from an old project of mine:

```
    form style="width:300px;margin: 0 auto;" action="/instructions" method="POST"

        strong
          p.input-label I'm currently at...

        input style="width:300px;" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your current address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="current_address" required="required"

        strong
          p.input-label And I need to get to...

        input style="width:300px;" id="autocomplete2" placeholder="Enter your destination address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" name="destination_address" required="required"


        input.button style="width:300px;" type="submit" value="What's the plan?"
```

Your inputs that you shared have different fields, some missing from the other, etc. Your first step should be making them identical in every way possible, and then slowly shifting one of them to your desired state.

I see you're using an older version of javascript, too. If possible you may want to consider refactoring to es5+

At the top you declare `placeSearch` and `autocomplete`, but not `autocomplete2`. This is another example of what I was suggesting earlier, about stepping through your code and ensuring that both inputs are being treated/created the exact same.

I see `initAutocomplete` is declared but never run. Is this intentional? Does the google module automatically call that function?

It seems to me like `addlatlong()` and `fillInAddress()` are the two functions you intend to use, one for `autocomplete` and the other for `autocomplete2`, but you reference `autocomplete` in both of them.

All in all, I think you've been messing with the code so much to try and make it work that you've lost sight of how it should be written in the end.

Perhaps starting a new file, fresh, and taking it one small step at a time might be the best way to figure out how to solve this.

Get one input working fully, as expected, and then add the next one in, step-by-step, the same way you implemented the first.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Brandon, thanks for the thorough answer.
A couple of questions. How can you tell I am using an older version of JS? I tried doing all of your suggested fixes but still couldn't get it working. I had one input fully working, it was trying to figure out how to add the second one is causing the issue.

Comment: @ChrisGrim I can tell you're using an older version of JS because you're using `var` a lot. Check out ES5+ syntax for `let` and `const`.


If you can get one input fully working, then you're a little over halfway there. The rest of the work is to figure out how to implement the second without breaking the first. That'll take some minor trial and error, but the number of variables involved here are very slim (e.g: the ID of the input, the order they're defined in, the script that actually does the autofilling, etc.) so you shouldn't have to spend too long on it.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks so much